# Async Task/ Mail not found. Mail.java is obviously there, so what is the issue

Tags: java, android

I have an android app registration form that has to send a successful signup email to the user, but onClick of the submit button, when I call that class, I get the following errors:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.asdqwe.utilities.Mail
    at net.asdqwe.utilities.EmailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.java:8)
    at net.asdqwe.activities.Signup$sendVerificationEmail.doInBackground(Signup.java:308)
    at net.asdqwe.activities.Signup$sendVerificationEmail.doInBackground(Signup.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is the code that calls it:

```
public class Signup extends Activity implements OnClickListener,  {

@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //some irrelevant code here

            Intent signupSuccessAvatarUpload = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupSuccessAvatarUpload.class);
            signupSuccessAvatarUpload.putExtra("userEmailID", userEmail);
            try {
                new sendVerificationEmail().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            addNewContact();
            startActivityForResult(signupSuccessAvatarUpload, 1);
            //finish();
    }
class sendVerificationEmail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                emailSender.sendEmail(userEmail, configurationz.EMAIL_OFFICIAL_ADDRESS, configurationz.EMAIL_SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP_SUBJECT, configurationz.EMAIL_SUCCESSFUL_SIGNUP_BODY(userName), null);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

here is the email sender class:

```
package net.asdqwe.utilities;

import net.asdqwe.utilities.Mail;

public class EmailSender {
    public boolean sendEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String message, String[] attachements) throws Exception {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        //code here
}
```

and in the same package there is the Mail class:

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
//lots of code here

public Mail() {
    host = "smtp.googlemail.com"; // default smtp server
    port = "465"; // default smtp port
    sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    user = ""; // username
    password = ""; // password
    from = ""; // email sent from
    subject = ""; // email subject
    body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    this.user = user;
    password = pass;
}
}
```

Comment: Something is strange here, if `EmailSender` and `Mail` are in the same package, why is there an import of `Mail` in `EmailSender`? Also, are you sure the packaged app is up to date (did you repackage, reinstall)?

Comment: well I imported Mail just in case. Either way its not working. As far as the app is concerned, I have uninstalled it and then installed it again and ran it. I will try restarting eclipse.

Comment: When using eclipse to deploy, sometimes the package is not updated, to be sure, you can uninstall on the device (or emulator) then redeploy with eclipse after a "clean project"

Comment: I just did that, no change :( Cleaned, refreshed, restarted Eclipse. Cleared cache, uninstalled app on device. I suppose there is something wrong with my code...

Comment: @J.Kowalski Did you import Mail class from elsewhere

Comment: I found the code for the Mail class on the internet, created a Mail.java class in my net.asdqwe.utilities. package where EmailSender.java is and thats it.

Comment: So wait a minute...you're calling `execute()` on an `AsyncTask` then immediately calling your `addNewContact()` method followed by `startActivityForResult(...)`??? It may not answer your question but are you really sure you want to do that? You do know how asynchronous operations work don't you?

Comment: @Squonk agree that those should be in onPostExecute but dont think that is what causes these problems. What happens if you do something like Mail mail = new net.asdqwe.utilities.Mail()?

Comment: Mail mail = new net.asdqwe.utilities.Mail() - this didnt help.

Comment: Also, what is the problem with my Async class, I am using that for the first time so Im not very familiar of how it should be implemented, can you clarify>?

Comment: @cYrixmorten : I wasn't trying to answer the question but if the OP doesn't have a grasp of how an `AsyncTask` works and is randomly putting imports in to code files trying to fix things then I think they should review everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Have you imported the jar files required for* **javax.mail.Authenticator** ?

You must import these libraries if you want to use `javax.mail.Authenticator`.

- [mail.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1/mail-1.4.1.jar) - contains the actual smtp implmentation
- [activation.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar) - needed by mail.jar

---

If the problem still persists, clean the project and follow instructions given below

Add this piece of code inside your **Mail** activity and `call this function from inside its default constructor`.

```
private static void fixClassLoaderIssue()
{
   ClassLoader myClassLoader = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader();
   Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(myClassLoader);
}
```

---

This is kind of trial & error method but works most of the times.

```
Remove the libraries, clean the project, restart eclipse and import 
them again & "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, I have those jars imported. About the code you provided - should I change MyClass with something else, or just paste it the way it is?

Comment: Well, changed MyClass to Mail, added this code, called it from the constructor but there is no change to what is happening. Also, cleaned and refreshed the project as well. I think the error is in the way I use async task...

Comment: @J.Kowalski Remove the libraries, clean the project, restart eclipse and import them again & "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. This is kind of trial & error method but works sometimes

Comment: wow, that helped me out, because when I went to Configure Build Path, I accidentally clicked on Order and Export and there the two libraries were, but there were no tickmarks in the checkboxes, so I checked them and the error was gone. Class was (probably) found, and I ran the application, and on Submit I was successfully redirected to the next activity. Email sending still doesnt work but I suppose that is another subject. If you provide that as the answer I would accept it. (I also reimported the libraries)

Comment: @J.Kowalski I think that is another question, please post a new question and provide all the necessary details there. I would be more than happy to help you. :)